# Gmail uses original "TO" address instead of "FROM" address for reply

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail

Using [CI's email library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html), I have the following code to send a pw to a user:

```
$email_html_message         =   '<html><body>'.
                                        'Your password is '.$password.'<br>'.
                                        '<a href="'.  base_url().'">Login to MySite</a>'.
                                        '</body></html>';


        $config['charset']  =   'iso-8859-1';
        $config['mailtype'] =   'html';
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('ray@MySite.com', 'MySite Admin');
        $this->email->to($user_email);
        $this->email->subject('Your MySite Login');
        $this->email->message($email_html_message);
        $this->email->send();
```

I tested this code on two accounts:  Gmail and my ISP's smtp email account.

Both tests sent an email, but here's the problem:

If I click reply through gmail, the Reply TO address is the address the e-mail was sent to:

[image]

This does not happen when I click reply through Windows Mail (e.g. my smtp account).

Here is the "original message" with headers from gmail:

```
Delivered-To: ray023@gmail.com
Received: by 10.114.17.8 with SMTP id k8csp412473ldd;
        Wed, 31 Oct 2012 07:27:06 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.220.142.79 with SMTP id p15mr18061226vcu.71.1351693626443;
        Wed, 31 Oct 2012 07:27:06 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bounce-cgi-moo.ray023@yourhostingaccount.com>
Received: from mailout12.yourhostingaccount.com (mailout12.yourhostingaccount.com. [65.254.253.98])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id p5si2963631vcv.55.2012.10.31.07.27.05;
        Wed, 31 Oct 2012 07:27:05 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounce-cgi-moo.ray023@yourhostingaccount.com designates 65.254.253.98 as permitted sender) client-ip=65.254.253.98;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce-cgi-moo.ray023@yourhostingaccount.com designates 65.254.253.98 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bounce-cgi-moo.ray023@yourhostingaccount.com
Received: from mailscan13.yourhostingaccount.com ([10.1.15.13] helo=mailscan13.yourhostingaccount.com)
    by mailout12.yourhostingaccount.com with esmtp (Exim)
    id 1TTZG5-0005Lf-Dt
    for ray023@gmail.com; Wed, 31 Oct 2012 10:27:05 -0400
Received: from impout01.yourhostingaccount.com ([10.1.55.1] helo=impout01.yourhostingaccount.com)
    by mailscan13.yourhostingaccount.com with esmtp (Exim)
    id 1TTZG2-0007KY-GM
    for ray023@gmail.com; Wed, 31 Oct 2012 10:27:02 -0400
Received: from cgi1703.yourhostingaccount.com ([10.1.12.150])
    by impout01.yourhostingaccount.com with NO UCE
    id HqT21k00s3EEVBe01qT2XN; Wed, 31 Oct 2012 10:27:02 -0400
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.0 cv=IICA+3TG c=1 sm=1 a=0bVzInp0yugA:10
 a=UT1nndvi2uwA:10 a=e1QP36Bl1McA:10 a=Gm7PUgscJ9MA:10 a=jPJDawAOAc8A:10
 a=mM4-eZ0ns8IA:10 a=PgEUWBzPAAAA:8 a=2RTERvT5bsMA:10 a=t2MNXjrCa7SdDSCJ3MYA:9
 a=wPNLvfGTeEIA:10 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=MvC2+Uy32Q89d9+Fzzoamg==:117
X-EN-OrigOutIP: 10.1.12.150
X-EN-IMPSID: HqT21k00s3EEVBe01qT2XN
Received: from moo.ray023 by cgi1703.yourhostingaccount.com with local (Exim)
    id 1TTZFR-0003Hw-20
    for ray023@gmail.com; Wed, 31 Oct 2012 10:26:25 -0400
X-EN-Info: U=moo.ray023 P=/index.php
X-EN-CGIUser: moo.ray023
X-EN-CGIPath: /index.php
X-EN-OrigIP: 173.191.128.136
To: ray023@gmail.com
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Your_MySite_Login?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 3651509:Email.php
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2012 10:26:24 -0400
From: "MySite Admin" <ray@MySite.com>
Reply-To: "ray@MySite.com" <ray@MySite.com>
X-Sender: ray@MySite.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5091351101295@MySite.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_50913511012dd"
X-EN-Timestamp: Wed, 31 Oct 2012 10:26:25 -0400
Sender:  "MySite Admin" <ray@MySite.com>

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_50913511012dd
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Your password is Login to MySite


--B_ALT_50913511012dd
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body>Your password is <br><a href=3D"http://MySite.com/">Logi=
n to MySite</a></body></html>

--B_ALT_50913511012dd--
```

Any idea on how to fix this with gmail?

Comment: All the headers look to be set properly, there is no reason gmail should be using that address for a reply. Does this happen consistently for other addresses as well? Also, don't send plaintext passwords through email. It is very poor security practice.

Comment: @Sammitch I only have two "users" on the site and they are both me.  I understand the security issue with the pw but taking it one step a time.  If I get beyond a single user, I'll code a more secure pw reset.

Comment: As far as I know, this is enforced by Google to prevent abuse. In other words, you can't change it.

Comment: @repox That's a peculiar security measure.  Gmail team:  "We will allow these types of e-mails to show up in the InBox (not spam) and allow the user to see the reply address; but, to prevent abuse, when they click reply, it'll show the user's own Gmail account."

Comment: @ray023 try Googling for the difference between the Return-Path and From header.

Comment: @Repox Why would I do that?  What nugget of info are you pushing me to learn?  That comment was so generic it was not helpful at all.  It's ok, though.  I found the answer on my own.

Comment: @ray023 Great - by some Googling or did the answer just fall down from the sky and accidentally end up in your lap?

Comment: @Repox I have yet to have an answer fall from the sky.  It was [just the right web query](http://tinyurl.com/gmailReplyTo) that pointed me to the answer for this unusual Use Case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing a Yahoo mail account and a separate Gmail account (both which worked btw), I found the problem was specifically with my gmail account only.

After searching a little, I found a [good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421234/gmail-appearing-to-ignore-reply-to) that pointed me [to this article](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/composing-and-sending-messages/ZRZA5KkTPAA) (special note made in bold):

> I have experienced the same issue with a PHP contact form which sends
>   mail to my Gmail account. If the "From" address is either the same as
>   the "To" address, or **is configured in GMail Settings as one of the
>   'Send As...' accounts, Gmail replies to the "To" address instead of
>   the "Reply-To" address.** An easy workaround is to specify a non-Gmail
>   "From" address. Now it works and Gmail properly respects the
>   "Reply-To" address. There is no doubt at all in my mind that this is a
>   bug in Gmail.

The part is bold is how my Gmail is set up.