# Reply-to - Send emails in codeigniter with gmail smtp

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, gmail

I created a contact form in my website, and, for send the e-mails to website account (contact@mywebsite.com), I'm using gmail smtp, using the same e-mail that I'll receive the messages.

So, users go to my website, click in contact page, fill the form with:
Name, Email, Message.

Than I send the email with the following code:

```
        $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'contact@mywebsite.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'utf-8'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $msg = $this->input->post('msg');
    $this->email->to('contact@mywebsite.com');
    $this->email->reply_to($email); //User email submited in form
    $this->email->from($email, $name);
    $this->email->subject('Conctact form');
    $this->email->message($msg);
    if ($this->email->send())
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        return false;
    }
```

The e-mail goes to my inbox in "contact@mywwebsite.com", I can read the message normally, but... when I click in "reply" instead of replying to the user that sent me the message, it replys to "me" (to contact@mywebsite.com).

I already configured the reply_to, to reply to users address, not mine, but still goes to contact@mywebsite.com.

How to fix this?
Should I change something more in the code or in gmail settings?

(PS.: I use gmail interface to read emails, directly from the site mail.google.com)

Thanks, in advance.

--
Also, when I receive the e-mail, It shows:
"From: 'Name in submitted form' "

Not:
"From: 'Name in submitted form' <'email in submitted form'>"
Like It should be.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail does this, and I don't believe there is any sort of work around.

The "from" address will only ever be the account you are using to send the email - you cannot simply "pass through" gmail's server.

If you need to do that, you'll need something like SendGrid or your own smtp server

Comment: With sendmail, there's any chance ...?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed By sending the e-mail through another user ...
I sent from me@mywebsite.com to contact@mywebsite.com, and when I clicked in reply, the user selected was the same that sent the message in form.

[GMail appearing to ignore Reply-To](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421234/gmail-appearing-to-ignore-reply-to)