# Laravel Mail ReplyTo being set but being ignored by mail clients

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.5

I have a Mailable class that sets a ReplyTo here:

```
class Feedback extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $text;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param $text
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, $text)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('feedback@mydomain.com')
            ->replyTo($this->user->email)
            ->subject("Feedback from {$this->user->name}")
            ->view('emails.feedback');
    }
}
```

This sends the email and when I inspect it I can see that the ReplyTo has been set to the address that I want however when I try and reply to the email the to address appears as the from address i.e. feedback@mydomain.com.

I can see the reply to is present in gmail and Mailtrap but the mail clients are ignoring it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's clearly not a laravel related issue, maybe this thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421234/gmail-appearing-to-ignore-reply-to